# What do $F(-∞, ∞)$ and $C(-∞, ∞)$ stand for?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What do $F(-∞, ∞)$ and $C(-∞, ∞)$ stand for? They are vector spaces, with $C(-∞, ∞)$ being a subspace of $F(-∞, ∞)$.

$C^1(-\infty, \infty)$ is a subspace of $C(-∞, ∞)$ and is defined as the set of all functions that are continuously differentiable.

Comment: you should probably provide some context as they might mean virtually anything you want. Normally I'd say $C(-\infty, \infty)$ are continuous real-valued functions on the real line, but that's still just a guess (a reasonable one tho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged this question with 'linear algebra' so I'll assume you saw this notation is a linear algebra course. Generally, as is the case with most undergraduate textbooks on linear algebra, the notation $F(-\infty,\infty)$ is the set of real-valued functions defined for all $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$ satisfying the rules that, for two functions $f$ and $g$:

\begin{align*}
(f+g)(x)&=f(x)+g(x)\\
(kf)(x)&=kf(x),
\end{align*}
for some scalar $k$.

Thus we can see that $F(-\infty,\infty)$ is a vector space. Also, we note that the set of all functions in $F(-\infty,\infty)$ that are *also* differentiable on their entire domain form a subspace of $F(-\infty,\infty)$. We denote this subspace as $C(-\infty,\infty)$.

Thus, $C^1(-\infty,\infty)$ denotes the subspace of functions that have a continuous first derivative, and $C^n(-\infty,\infty)$ denotes the subspace of functions that have a continuous $n$th derivative.

*In summary*: $F(-\infty,\infty)$ is vector space of real-valued continuous functions satisfying the vector space axioms and $C(-\infty,\infty)$ is the subspace of $F$ that contains the functions that have differentiable over their domain.